# Issue with pre_get_posts on custom post type archive pages

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, pre-get-posts

**Overview**

1. I am creating a theme which has 2 custom post types (as custom plugins):

   1. Articles
   2. Reviews
2. I have also created `single-articles.php` and `archive-articles.php` templates inside the plugin. Same for Reviews CPT.
3. BOTH the custom post types use the **default** WordPress Taxonomies (categories and tags)
4. My Reading Settings are set to "A Static Page"

   1. Front page: Home ( a Custom `front-page.php` file I created)
   2. Posts Page: The "Site News" page (which I want to show *BOTH* posts *AND* CPT's)

**The Problem**

After creating a regular post *and* a post based on the Articles CPT, I went to the Main Posts page (The Site News) wherein I did **not** see the custom post type (only the post using the standard `post` type).

After some searching (i'm a noob) I understood that if I wanted to display CPT's on the main posts page, I would have to write a filter using `pre_get_posts`.

So, to recap: I wish to show

1. BOTH regular posts AND Custom Post Types (CPT's) on the Main Posts page
2. BOTH regular posts AND Custom Post Types (CPT's) for the Category Archives pages

**Here's What I Did**

```
// Add custom post types to the default loop (ref: http://bit.ly/1bqeBJC)
function odigbs_add_custom_types( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin()  && !is_preview() ) {
        if ( (is_home() || is_category() || is_tag() || is_archive()  || is_feed() ) && $query->is_main_query()  ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'articles', 'reviews') );
            return $query;
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'odigbs_add_custom_types' );
```

I'm sure this is **not the right way** to craft this filter, but I cannot find any article that explains this concept thoroughly... so i'm *wingin it*.

**The Results**

1. If I go to: `http://site.dev/the-site-news/` (the main posts page from Reading Settings), I now ***DO*** see all of my custom post types ***and*** it does use the `single-{post_type}.php` file inside the plugin.
2. If I click on any of the taxonomy terms the page goes to: `http://site.dev/category/{some term}/` ***and*** it does use the `archive-{post_type}.php` file inside the plugin.

***But...***

1. If I point my browser to `http://site.dev/{custom_post_type}`, (i.e. not using the category) to see the archives for that CPT, the site throws all kind of errors.
2. But if I disable the filter, then I ***can*** now go to `http://starter.dev/{custom_post_type}/`, but I'm right back where I started with only default posts showing on the main posts page. No custom Post types.

**Questions**

1. Is (as I suspect) the problem is in the filter?
2. If so, how **should** it be written?

I hope I clearly articulated the drama...

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are the errors you get?

Comment: Upon second look, it's a warning. Not an error. The message is "WARNING: C:\wamp\www\my-theme\wp-includes\post.php:1038 - Illegal offset type in isset or empty".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look [in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/query.php#L1573), we'll see under what conditions `is_archive` is true:

```
if ( $this->is_post_type_archive
|| $this->is_date
|| $this->is_author
|| $this->is_category
|| $this->is_tag
|| $this->is_tax )
    $this->is_archive = true;
```

The issue is that `is_archive` is triggering your filter on your post type archive. If you want to exclude those, either make sure it's *not* [`is_post_type_archive`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive), or target the other archives by checking if it's an author or date archive as well as tag and category and remove the check for `is_archive`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your CPTs to show on regular archive pages (cateogires, main query etc) but when searching only your CPTs you get again your CPTs with all regular posts etc..

Here is what I made and for now as I have seen it is working well, but you never know where you can get any error so here, try it and see if it works well for you.

change YOURCPT for your cpt :)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpstck_get_YOURCPT_into_posts' );
function wpstck_get_YOURCPT_into_posts($query){


    if ( !is_post_type_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'YOURCPT' ) );
            return $query;
        }
}
```